# Docker compose "tty" is not working in windows container on windows 10

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I am writing DockerFile for the Python/Flask application in windows 10 using windows container. It gives an error when adds `stdin_open: true` and `tty: true` commands in the docker-compose file while running command `docker-compose up --build`.

**Error:**

```
* Serving Flask app "application"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 81, in main
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 203, in perform_command
  File "compose\metrics\decorator.py", line 18, in wrapper
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 1216, in up
  File "compose\cli\log_printer.py", line 106, in run
  File "compose\cli\log_printer.py", line 110, in write
  File "colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 41, in write
  File "colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 162, in write
  File "colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 184, in write_and_convert
  File "colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 256, in convert_osc
  File "colorama\winterm.py", line 169, in set_title
  File "colorama\win32.py", line 152, in SetConsoleTitle
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'ValueError'>: embedded null character
[15848] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

**DockerFile:**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809


ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]


ENV PYTHONIOENCODING UTF-8
ENV PYTHON_VERSION 3.9.6
ENV PYTHON_RELEASE 3.9.6

WORKDIR C:/app

RUN $url = ('https://www.python.org/ftp/python/{0}/python-{1}-amd64.exe' -f $env:PYTHON_RELEASE, $env:PYTHON_VERSION); \
    Write-Host ('Downloading {0} ...' -f $url); \
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; \
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile 'python.exe'; \
    \
    Write-Host 'Installing ...'; \
# https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#installing-without-ui
    $exitCode = (Start-Process python.exe -Wait -NoNewWindow -PassThru \
        -ArgumentList @( \
            '/quiet', \
            'InstallAllUsers=1', \
            'TargetDir=C:\Python', \
            'PrependPath=1', \
            'Shortcuts=0', \
            'Include_doc=0', \
            'Include_pip=0', \
            'Include_test=0' \
        ) \
    ).ExitCode; \
    if ($exitCode -ne 0) { \
        Write-Host ('Running python installer failed with exit code: {0}' -f $exitCode); \
        Get-ChildItem $env:TEMP | Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime | Select-Object -First 1 | Get-Content; \
        exit $exitCode; \
    } \
    \
# the installer updated PATH, so we should refresh our local value
    $env:PATH = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine); \
    \
    Write-Host 'Verifying install ...'; \
    Write-Host '  python --version'; python --version; \
    \
    Write-Host 'Removing ...'; \
    Remove-Item python.exe -Force; \
    Remove-Item $env:TEMP/Python*.log -Force; \
    \
    Write-Host 'Complete.'

# if this is called "PIP_VERSION", pip explodes with "ValueError: invalid truth value '<VERSION>'"
ENV PYTHON_PIP_VERSION 21.2.4
# https://github.com/pypa/get-pip
ENV PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL https://github.com/pypa/get-pip/raw/c20b0cfd643cd4a19246ccf204e2997af70f6b21/public/get-pip.py
ENV PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256 fa6f3fb93cce234cd4e8dd2beb54a51ab9c247653b52855a48dd44e6b21ff28b

RUN Write-Host ('Downloading get-pip.py ({0}) ...' -f $env:PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL); \
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; \
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $env:PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL -OutFile 'get-pip.py'; \
    Write-Host ('Verifying sha256 ({0}) ...' -f $env:PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256); \
    if ((Get-FileHash 'get-pip.py' -Algorithm sha256).Hash -ne $env:PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256) { \
        Write-Host 'FAILED!'; \
        exit 1; \
    }; \
    \
    Write-Host ('Installing pip=={0} ...' -f $env:PYTHON_PIP_VERSION); \
    python get-pip.py \
        --disable-pip-version-check \
        --no-cache-dir \
        ('pip=={0}' -f $env:PYTHON_PIP_VERSION) \
    ; \
    Remove-Item get-pip.py -Force; \
    \
    Write-Host 'Verifying pip install ...'; \
    pip --version; \
    \
    Write-Host 'Complete.'

COPY . C:/app

RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

RUN setx FLASK_ENV "developement"
RUN setx FLASK_APP "application"
CMD ["flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

**Docker-compose:**

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  flaskapi:
    container_name: flask_app
    image: flask_api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    stdin_open: true (this is problematic)
    tty: true (this is problematic)
    volumes:
      - .:C:/app
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
```

I want to open the running container inside the shell. Without `tty` and `stdin`, I am unable to do that because `docker-compose exec -it <container_name> /bin/bash` is not working.

Can anyone please help me out with how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to delete most of those settings.  A Flask application doesn't usually pay any attention to its stdin, so you can delete the settings causing problems.  You also shouldn't need to override `container_name:` or the `image:` name, and overwriting the application code with `volumes:` mount can lead to hard-to-reproduce problems.

Comment: I have deleted `tty` and `stdin` settings and it's working but I want to open the container in the shell too. 

If I don't use `volumes` then the updated code is not picked by the docker container.

Comment: If you run the Flask application in a non-Docker virtual environment, how would you get a shell inside it?  (Why do you need `docker exec` here?)